# Transfer an image from CDC to CBitmap

Tags: c++, mfc, transfer, change-data-capture, cbitmap

How can I transfer an image from CDC to CBitmap?
The problem in whole:
I have a big image into CBitmap A. I need to transfer parts of this image to a number of CBitmap for the storage into a vector, because I can't use a number of CDC for this :)
I make a prepared CDC into a cycle (get a neccessary part of CBitmap A) and then I need to transfer it to CBitmap x.
How can I do it?

Here's my code:

```
m_bitmaps.clear();
m_bitmaps.reserve(4);

CDC SourceDC, destDC;
SourceDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pMainDC);
destDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pMainDC);

CBitmap bmpWhole; // bmp 200*200
bmpWhole.LoadBitmap(IDB_TEST_BITMAP);
SourceDC.SelectObject(&bmpWhole);

//pMainDC->BitBlt(0,0,200,200,&SourceDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);
```

// It's OK - I got a source picture

```
for (int x=100; x>=0; x-=100)
    for (int y=100; y>=0; y-=100)
    {
        CBitmap *destBitmap = new CBitmap();
        destBitmap->CreateCompatibleBitmap(&destDC, 100, 100);

        CBitmap *oldBitmap = destDC.SelectObject(destBitmap);

        destDC.BitBlt(0,0,100,100,&SourceDC,x,y,SRCCOPY);

        pMainDC->BitBlt(x*1.1,y*1.1,100,100,&destDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);
```

// I got black squares here! - something wrong with previous code

```
        m_bitmaps.push_back(destBitmap);

        destDC.SelectObject(oldBitmap);
    }

bmpWhole.DeleteObject();
destDC.DeleteDC();
SourceDC.DeleteDC();
```

// And later CBitmaps are black squares

---

**I found the solution!**

**Parsing the CBitmap and initializing the vector**

```
m_bitmaps.clear();
m_bitmaps.reserve(4);

CDC SourceDC, destDC;
SourceDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pMainDC);

CBitmap bmpWhole;
bmpWhole.LoadBitmap(IDB_TEST_BITMAP);
SourceDC.SelectObject(&bmpWhole);

for (int x=100; x>=0; x-=100)
    for (int y=100; y>=0; y-=100)
    {
        CImage *destImage = new CImage();
        destImage->Create(100, 100, 24);

        destDC.Attach(destImage->GetDC());
        destDC.BitBlt(0,0,100,100,&SourceDC,x,y,SRCCOPY);
        destDC.Detach();
        destImage->ReleaseDC();

        m_bitmaps.push_back(destImage);
    }

bmpWhole.DeleteObject();
destDC.DeleteDC();
SourceDC.DeleteDC();
```

**Draw:**

```
WORD nShift=0;
for (auto iter = m_bitmaps.begin(); iter != m_bitmaps.end(); ++iter, nShift+=110)
{
    CBitmap* pBitmap = CBitmap::FromHandle((*iter)->operator HBITMAP());

    CDC memDC;
    memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pMainDC);
    memDC.SelectObject(pBitmap);
    pMainDC->BitBlt(nShift, 0, 100, 100, &memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you selected the CBitmap object into the device context?

Comment: I wrote my code into the first post.

Answer (score 1):

Create another device context and one by one create and select your target bitmaps into it and use `BitBlt` to copy portions of the source bitmap into them. Below is an example of how you might do this.

```
// Create a DC compatible with the display
// this is used to copy FROM the source bitmap
sourceDC.CreateDC(NULL); 
sourceDC.SelectObject(&sourceBitmap);

// Create another device context for the destination bitmap
destDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&sourceDC);
for(int i = 0; i < numBitmaps; i++)
{
    // Determine the x, y, sourceX, sourceY, with and height here
    // ...

    // create a new bitmap
    CBitmap *destBitmap = new CBitmap();
    destBitmap->CreateCompatibleBitmap(&destDC, width, height);
    // Select the bitmap into the destination device context
    CBitmap *oldBitmap = destDC.SelectObject(destBitmap);

    // copy the bitmap
    destDC.BitBlt(x, y, width, height, &sourceDC, sourceX, sourceY, SRCCOPY);

    // add it to the vector    
    bitmapVector.push_back(destBitmap);

    // Clean up
    destDC.SelectObject(oldBitmap);
}
```

I omitted error checking for simplicity. If you are using C++11 or Boost I recommend using `unique_ptr` to manage the lifetime of the bitmap object. Otherwise you need to `delete` it at the appropriate place such as the destructor.